# Unable to install the package rmetadata in R

Tags: r, metadata, article, ropensci

My primary goal is to extract metadata of an article using the title and journal name. To do so, `rmetadata` package is useful according to the blog `https://ropensci.org/blog/2013/03/15/r-metadata/`. However, I'm unable to install the package using the `install_github()` function. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You should show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repo is now archived at https://github.com/ropensci-archive/rmetadata

It does install though, try `remotes::install_github("ropensci-archive/rmetadata")`

However, that package is no longer maintained. You probably want to use `rcrossref`, see the docs at https://docs.ropensci.org/rcrossref/. e.g.,

```
install.packages("rcrossref")
res = cr_works(flq = c(`query.container-title` = 'Ecology', 
 `query.bibliographic` = 'An assessment of statistical methods for
  nonindependent data in ecological meta-analyses'))
```

See the Crossref API docs http://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html#/Works/get_works as well